# replace link text with graphic through css

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I want to replace the links in my bootstrap navigation with icons. But only when A class is added to the navigation. I currently have a fixed navigation which 'shrinks' when the user scrolls using

html (head)

```
 $(function(){
   var shrinkHeader = 100;
   $(window).scroll(function() {
var scroll = getCurrentScroll();
  if ( scroll >= shrinkHeader ) {
       $('header').addClass('shrink');
    }
    else {
        $('header').removeClass('shrink');
    }
 });
```

with the 'shrink' class added to header div when scrolled 100px.

css

```
.navbar-custom .nav>li>a {
   font-size: 1.15em;
   font-weight: 400;
   etc...

header.shrink { 
  min-height: 50px;
}

header.shrink .nav>li>a { line-height: 50px; }
```

when the 'shrink' class gets added to the .header I want the links (which are currently text) to turn into icons. not sure the approach for this

I have fontawesome installed and usable

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In my previous project, I had the icons already inside the DOM but only hidden. I made them display if the parent had a certain class

```
.nav>li>a>.fa { display: none; }
.shrink .nav.li.a.fa { display:block; }
```

Edit:

Added [jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/cattails27/0b5h20Lc/)

Edit2:

Updated [jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/0b5h20Lc/1/). You can add font awesome icons using pseudo classes. You can get the unicode easily with a bit of googling

Comment: seems to work. I'll have to find a way to animate it or something someday. Thanks for the help

Comment: problem is though, I am using wordpress, so I don't have the ability to add icons as you have shown (in lists)

Comment: that makes things interesting, let me update the fiddle

Comment: will that work with the dynamic wordpress nav. As I mentioned I can't hardcode each link directly

Comment: you just have to know which elements you have to target, it doesn't require you to do any html changes

Comment: I just am not sure how to apply it since it is hard coded to the links in your example

Comment: okay it would helpful if you could post some markup in the question.

Comment: The navigation is brought in with the code I mentioned in the question. The links are created in the wp-admin menu panel. I could add a custom css to each link but I have to provide content, so perhapse I could replace the content with a graphic with css

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/99291/discussion-between-jkris-and-user3550879).

Answer (score 0):

I would add the HTML markup for the icons inside your anchor tag and hide it by default:

```
header .nav > li > a > span.icon {
    display: none;
}
```

And show it when the header has the .shrink class:

```
header.shrink .nav > li > a > span.icon {
    display: block; (or inline)
}
```

Comment: will that not add extra spacing or issues like that? I forgot to mention that I am using wordpress

Comment: No, display: none; takes care of that for you.

Comment: You can use the same trick on the text to toggle it. E.g.: span.label { }